# can't git push with the current i.p address,what to do?

Tags: git, push

when i git push -u origin master it is saying that it cant access to some old i.p address 18.217.76.112:8080 but i am now using 3.17.37.46 this I.p,it is not accessing with this,cant able to push what to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the command `git push -u origin master`, `origin` is an alias of the remote url. Run `git remote -v` to see what it is. It could be something like `http://18.217.76.112:8080/some/repo.git`. You could try either:

```
git push -u http://3.17.37.46:8080/some/repo.git master
```

or

```
git remote set-url origin http://3.17.37.46:8080/some/repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

or

```
git remote add new http://3.17.37.46:8080/some/repo.git
git push -u new master
```

The first solution is disposable. The second updates `origin` with a new url. The third creates a new remote.